# how to get value of Threadlocal from current Thread in java?

Tags: java, thread-local

How to get value of Thread-local from current Thread?
I am trying to get the value of Thread-local from current Thread but can't find any help online.

Comment: you mean, value associated with a current thread? Then use `.get()`.

Answer (score 5):

Read the Javadoc for `ThreadLocal`. There are only 4 methods on `ThreadLocal`; the one you need is obviously [`ThreadLocal.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#get()):

> Returns the value in the current thread's copy of this thread-local variable.